# Differential equation regarding two body center

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

I'm currently reading a paper about the two/three body center problem.
In this paper there is this equation, which i'm not sure how to come up with. My problem is, that the functuon evolved radial aswell as vectorial dependence and I'm not sure how to apply the nabla operator to this function.

To sum up I have two questions:

1) What ist the relation of (28) to the two body coloumb problem?

2) How can I proove that (29) is really a solution of (28)?
It would be very nice if someone could help me with this.
Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: It is stated that the solution of 28 is well known from two body coulomb problem. I dont see why

Comment: I wonder how to apply nabla to my function f to verify that the solution is correct

Comment: I edited as you sughested

Comment: Thank you. Let's clarify again (going by your comments). You have two questions: (1) what is the relation of (28) to the two body coulomb problem and (2) how to prove that (29) is really a solution to (28)?

Comment: Yes. This is exaktly what i look for.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer one of your questions which I understood as "how to prove that (29) is really a solution to (28)?"

First, let us assume $\mathbf{x}=\{x,y,z\}$ is a radius vector in 3D Cartesian coordinate system. The following will be valid for any number of dimensions though.

Further: $\mathbf{a}=\{a_x,a_y,a_z\}$ is a constant vector.

We will use the absolute values of both vectors which are:

$$|\mathbf{x}| =\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$

$$|\mathbf{a}| =a=\sqrt{a_x^2+a_y^2+a_z^2}$$

And the dot product:

$$\mathbf{ax}=a_xx+a_yy+a_zz$$

Nabla operator is represented in this coordinate system as:

$$\nabla=\mathbf{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\mathbf{j}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+\mathbf{k}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$$

And:

$$\mathbf{a}\nabla=a_x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+a_y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+a_z\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$$

Our equation is:

$$\mathbf{a} \nabla f(\mathbf{x})= - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} \tag{28}$$

The proposed solution is:

$$f(\mathbf{x})^{\pm}= \pm \frac{1}{a} \ln \left( a\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} \mp  (a_xx+a_yy+a_zz)\right) \tag{29}$$

Let us choose one of the signs to be more clear and  compute the partial derivatives:

$$a_x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{a} \frac{1}{a\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} -  (a_xx+a_yy+a_zz)} \left(a \frac{a_xx}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} - a_x^2 \right)$$

$$a_y \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{1}{a} \frac{1}{a\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} -  (a_xx+a_yy+a_zz)} \left(a \frac{a_yy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} - a_y^2 \right)$$

$$a_z\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{a} \frac{1}{a\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} -  (a_xx+a_yy+a_zz)} \left(a \frac{a_zz}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} - a_z^2 \right)$$

Now we can finally write:

$$\mathbf{a} \nabla f(\mathbf{x})=\frac{1}{a} \frac{1}{a\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} -  (a_xx+a_yy+a_zz)} \left(a \frac{a_xx+a_yy+a_zz}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} - a^2 \right)$$

$$\mathbf{a} \nabla f(\mathbf{x})=\frac{1}{a\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} -  (a_xx+a_yy+a_zz)} \left(\frac{a_xx+a_yy+a_zz}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} - a \right)$$

$$\mathbf{a} \nabla f(\mathbf{x})=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$$

I think it is obvious that (29) really is a solution to (28)

Comment: Thank you so much.. sometimes it's so easy. I was confused by the mix up of the vector and absolut value..

Comment: @simon.v, you are welcome. Though in the future please try to better formulate questions on this site, type out the equations (as I did here) instead of using pictures and make sure your text is easily understandable.

Comment: I will do my best, Yuriy. Thank you so much for taking the time to clear things up for me :-)

Comment: As for Coulomb problem, the right hand side is clearly a Coulomb type potential, though I'm not sure what exactly the left hand side is supposed to be

Comment: I'll reread the paper on the weekend and rethink about it and let you know the answer if come close to it!